# np.eye() Memory Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to train a machine learning model on batches of images and their corresponding labels. The labels have to be One-Hot Encoded before feeding them into the network.

This is what the training loop looks like:

```
# epochs = 500
# iterations = 50
# nclasses = 15,000
# batch_size = 64

for e in range(epochs):
    print("EPOCH %d" % e)
    for i in range(iterations):
        # batch() produces an array of labels of size (64,)
        imgs, lbls = batch()
        # Batch-wise 1-Hot Encoding
        lbls = np.eye(nclasses)[lbls] # <-- Memory Error here!
        # More processing
```

Whenever I try to run this, I get a Memory error in `lbls = np.eye(nclasses)[lbls]`, not right away, but in the middle of the 60th epoch or so. The number is classes is pretty large (15k), and I've played around with different batch sizes, but all this does is postpone when the Memory Error occurs.

`batch()` does the following:

```
def batch():
# Provides a random array of images and labels of size batch_size
# labels_train is an array of shape (1217958,)
    p = np.random.choice(np.array(range(train_total)), batch_size, replace=False)
    imgs = create_images(list(inputs_train[p]))
    return imgs, labels_train[p]
```

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could tell me why this happens somewhere in the middle and not right away, and if you could suggest a work around! Thank you very much!

Comment: With `np.eye(nclasses)`, you are trying to create an array of 64 bit values with shape 15000x15000.  That will require about 1.8 gigabytes of memory.  How much memory does your computer have?

Comment: That seems like an inefficient method for one-hot encoding.  Have you looked at something like [`OneHotEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) in `scikit-learn`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser My computer has 32 GB of RAM installed. I'll try the `scikit-learn` OneHot Encoder and see if that makes a difference! Thank you!

Comment: If you continue to use `np.eye(nclasses)`, you could at least move that call out of the inner loop, so you aren't repeatedly allocating and then freeing 1.8 gigabytes.  The memory used by some other part of your code might be increasing steadily, and the fact that it runs out in the call to `np.eye()` is only because it happens to allocate a relatively large chunk.

Comment: Another alternative for a one-hot encoder: `onehot = np.zeros((len(lbls), nclasses), dtype=int); onehot[np.arange(len(lbls)), lbls] = 1`.  You can probably find many other implementations here on SO; try searching for "[numpy] one-hot" or terms like that.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thank you! I'm trying the scikit-learn label binarizer for now. I need the call in the inner loop as I need different batches of data each iteration. Would you mind telling me why using `np.eye()` is inefficient?